# pack a software in Python using py2exe with 'libiomp5md.dll' not found

Tags: python, runtime-error, exe, executable, py2exe

I have Python 2.7 on Window 7 OS. I wish to pack my project.py in an Executable using py2exe. Following the instruction i wrote a setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["project.py"])
```

and I got this message

[image]

i tried to exclude '**libiomp5md.dll**'

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["SegmentationAccuracy.py"])

dll_excludes = ['libiomp5md.dll']
```

but always i got the same error message **"error: libiomo5md.dll: No such file or directory"**

my executable contains:

```
import math
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
import ogr
from progressbar import ProgressBar
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
nan = np.nan
```

Comment: You can copy output from the windows console by clicking on the icon in the top left and going to "Edit->Mark" and hit "enter" to copy

Comment: This question is ten months old; could you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem, but calling `import numpy` within `setup.py` resolved the issue

Comment: Hey @ChrisB. I just moved the libiomp5md.dll file in the folder of setup.py and it works

Comment: adding "import numpy" worked for me too. You don't really want to be moving DLLs around, as other components may depend on them being in a certain place.

Answer (score 9):

`libiomp5md.dll` is from the Intel C compiler, and is used for `OpenMP` multiprocessing operations. I expect that your code involves `numpy` or code compiled with the Intel compiler, and so your `py2exe` build depends on it.

You can't simply create a build without it, so I would suggest finding it on your system and copying it to the directory where you run `python setup.py py2exe` . Hint, I have a copy in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core`

[If you really want to exclude it you will have to compile `numpy` manually with Visual Studio or Msys.]

Once you have `libiomp5md.dll` in the directory that you're executing `python setup.py py2exe` then you only need to remove the `exclude_dll` line (as you don't want to be excluding it...)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["SegmentationAccuracy.py"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I had to install numpy on a machine, did it with mingw gcc compiler.
I confirmed: copy of dll found in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\

I just copied it to the working directory before launching setup.

Nothing special to tune in setup.py, dependencies are automatically found.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had the same problem. It turned out that a .pyd file in sklearn was referencing libiomp5md.dll. Py2exe looks in two places for your DLL - on the path environment variable and in the same directory that the .pyd file is in. libiomp5md.dll is in neither. Py2exe pretty much gives up and instead of giving a full path name such as c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libiomp5md.dll, it says "libiomp5md.dll" which, later on, it can't find.

I'm impatient.
I added a line within my setup file:

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(numpy.core.**file**)

and that's where libiomp5md.dll is. Now everything works. Just make sure you do this in your code prior to calling setup and it will for you too.

Comment: I added 'import numpy' because it told me that numpy was not defined, now I'm getting "'module' object has no attribute 'file'"