# pyTables py2exe example does not run

Tags: python, py2exe, pytables

I have this code based on [this example](http://pytables.github.io/cookbook/py2exe_howto.html):

```
from tables import *

class Particle(IsDescription):
    name = StringCol(16) # 16-character String
    idnumber = Int64Col() # Signed 64-bit integer
    ADCcount = UInt16Col() # Unsigned short integer
    TDCcount = UInt8Col() # Unsigned byte
    grid_i = Int32Col() # Integer
    grid_j = IntCol() # Integer (equivalent to Int32Col)
    pressure = Float32Col() # Float (single-precision)
    energy = FloatCol() # Double (double-precision)

h5file = openFile("tutorial.h5", mode="w", title="Test file")
group = h5file.createGroup("/", "detector", "Detector information")
table = h5file.createTable(group, "readout", Particle, "Readout example")

print h5file

particle = table.row

for i in xrange(10):
    particle['name'] = 'Particle: %6d' % i
    particle['TDCcount'] = i % 256
    particle['ADCcount'] = (i*256) % (1<<16)
    particle['grid_i'] = i
    particle['grid_j'] = 10 - i
    particle['pressure'] = float(i*i)
    particle['energy'] = float(particle['pressure']**4)
    particle['idnumber'] = i * (2**34)
    particle.append()

table.flush()

table = h5file.root.detector.readout
pressure = [x['pressure'] for x in table.iterrows() if x['TDCcount']>3 and
                                                       20<=x['pressure']<50]

print pressure

h5file.close()
```

And I am compiling it with py2exe with the following setup.py file:

```
import os
import shutil

print '*\n*\nBegin clean up...\n*\n*'

build_folder_name = 'build'
dist_folder_name = 'dist'

build_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.curdir, build_folder_name))
if os.path.exists(build_path):
    print 'removing folder: {0}'.format(build_path)
    shutil.rmtree(build_path)

dist_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.curdir, dist_folder_name))
if os.path.exists(dist_path):
    print 'removing folder: {0}'.format(dist_path)
    shutil.rmtree(dist_path)

print '*\n*\nClean up done. Setup will now begin...\n*\n*'

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import numpy # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478230/pack-a-software-in-python-using-py2exe-with-libiomp5md-dll-not-found

excludes_list = []

includes_list = [
    'numpy',
    'tables',
    'tables.utilsextension'
]

setup(
    console=['run_me.py']
    , options={
        'py2exe': {
            'excludes': excludes_list
            , 'includes': includes_list
            , 'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe', 'MSVCP90.dll', 'libzmq.dll']
        }
    }
)
```

The generated executable does not run and produces this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_me.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "tables\__init__.pyc", line 82, in <module>
  File "tables\utilsextension.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "tables\utilsextension.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "utilsextension.pyx", line 275, in init tables.utilsextension (tables\utilsextension.c:15283)
ImportError: No module named _comp_lzo
```

I'm trying to understand why this error occurs and how to fix it. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My environment is Win7 and Python 2.7.3. Other packages were installed via pip or from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: No luck. We stopped including pyTables in out build and solved out problem with a workaround. I would have hoped that the PyTables people would offer support.

Answer (score 0):

adding 'tables._comp_lzo' to the includes_list solves for the problem for those that have the issue