# OMP warning when numpy 1.9.2+MKL is packaged with py2exe

Tags: python, numpy, py2exe

I get the following warning when i package my python application using py2exe to a single exe

```
OMP: Warning #178: Function GetModuleHandleEx failed:
OMP: System error #126: The specified module could not be found.
```

is there a way to hide the warning or to fix the issue. A similar issue was posted with numpy 1.8.0 where the issue was resolved using numpy 1.8.1rc1. I am already using the latest version of numpy.

Platform Info
Windows 7
WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.5

Comment: how did you get your numpy? maybe through python(x,y)?

Comment: I got numpy as part of winpython which is similar to python xy

Comment: Then please try my answer below. Probably it's the same problem with how numpy is compiled by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you got numpy from python(x,y), then try the numpy official one from sourceforge. I had [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22412984/566035) previously with py2exe and numpy from python(x,y).