# Pip, Python Wheels and Numpy compilation Issues

Tags: python, numpy, python-wheel

I was using numpy with the MKL compilation however when developing a GUI program i hit the following
[OMP warning when numpy 1.9.2+MKL is packaged with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461231/omp-warning-when-numpy-1-9-2mkl-is-packaged-with-py2exe)

Therefore I need to use the non-mkl numpy version, so I added the second wheel to my wheelhouse.

```
numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
numpy-1.9.2-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

in my requirements file, I can state the following

numpy==1.9.2

Then pip installs one of the above wheels .

Is there a way to tell pip which of the above numpy versions that I want to install from the above list ?
I cannot find a generic way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the used BLAS library name to the local version identifier like

```
numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
numpy-1.9.2+atlas-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

and then specify the version like

```
numpy==1.9.2+atlas
```